# slider is not moving

Tags: qt

I am implementing slider in my app like below...

```
Slider = new QSlider(this);
Slider->setOrientation (  Qt::Horizontal );
```

when I run the app it shows the slider but i cant able to move the slider handle...

what I am doing wrong ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the minimum and maximum values with:

```
void    setMaximum ( int )
void    setMinimum ( int )
```

Optionally set the initial value with `void setValue ( int )`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it all in the constructor:

```
QSlider::QSlider( int minValue, int maxValue, int pageStep, int value, Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent, const char * name = 0 )
```

like this:

```
Slider= new QSlider( 0, 100, 1, 0, Qt::Horizontal, this);
```

Assuming you are using a percentage of 0<->100,